# how to index on frequently updated field in cassandra

Tags: database, indexing, cassandra

I have a column family with fields userid,name,gender,email,status. Where userid, email is the primary key.

I have created secondary index on status which is of type tinyint.

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX users_status_idx ON custom.users (status) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex';
```

The status value is continuously updated(daily 20 million records).

While starting the program it will take 0 seconds to retrieve data from database. As the time increases time taken to retrieve data increases.

What is the best way to index on such type of field(status)?

Comment: Is *crore* 10M?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the best way is to denormalize your data by adding two (or more, depending on the number of states you have) tables, one for each status **you usually query for**, and move around users between these tables. If the number of users that change status on daily basis is very high, you'll need to take special care on your tables design, eg clever partition keys, in order to avoid problems with tombstones.

Comment: also I want to add that for a big amount of data you should think about future schema changes, cause full index rebuild (and this will happen if ull change it) will be very painful on production. You can use also custom indexes like stratio based on lucene (https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index)